Automate a task when a Microsoft Defender ATP Alert is detected
I have a project that will use the Microsoft Power Automate tool to create a task on Azure DevOps when a new WDATP alert is detected on Microsoft Defender ATP.
I think I've done everything right, except that it doesn't work, where could I have gone wrong?
Here's what I tried
enter image description here
enter image description here
